# Nothing happen when the button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have in my VB.NET form, two textBoxes and I want return its values on a messageBox when I click on the button, but I still have no result and nothing is happen.

```
Public Class Form3

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            MessageBox.Show(Textnom.Text.ToString & "  " & Textplace.Text.ToString)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

What is wrong with `Click` event?

Comment: Have you used breakpoints? Do you mean the event is not triggered?

Comment: No I don't use breakpoints ,Yes the event is not triggered because the MessageBox is not appearing

Comment: use break point and see if is it going to fire or not , change the name of your buuton and see is there going to make error or not

Comment: You should always use breakpoints and check the flow of execution while debugging. A lot of things could go wrong, even when you are certain that your logic is right.

Comment: The most common cause is that either your button or the textboxes are not named what you have shown in the code here.

Comment: Please attache the code from the designer file.

Comment: Look in the designer and confirm that your button is still named Button1

Comment: the names are correct and even if I use breakpoint I don't get any exception

Comment: Delete the button and the code and then add a new one. Double-click the new button in the designer which will bring you to its click event in the code. Enter your MessageBox there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert so please backup the file before trying this

Vb.net sometimes used to freeze like this when we used to code.
So just (Backup first) and go to the Visual studio 2010 folder, goto Projects folder, go inside the folder of your project, go into the obj folder and delete the  x86 file.

Retry to run and it should

In short delete the x86 file in the obj folder and run. It will work